# call different-different listviews by click on each listview item row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

i am making an app in which i am getting data into listview using xml parser,and using each listview item row i need to open another listview, i am able to open another listview, but whenever i call another listview then i am not getting view of required listview everytime i am getting view of first list view with some field(s) name only those are matched in both the listviews like: title and description, i have tried by many ways but still not able to solve this, someone guide me how can i achieve my target.  Noe:- i am using different- different views, for every clicked item row in listview, like:- in some listviews i am only using textviews, imageview, imagebutton and somewhere i am using textviews,imageview,imagebutton along with checkboxes. i know how to call another activity using listview item row and i have tried this code by using separate activities for each and every item list along with their different-different xmls:-

FancyItem.java Code:-

```
public class FancyItem extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://***.net/android/fabriclist.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_FANCY = "fancy"; // parent node
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "desc";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL= "thumb_url";
static final String KEY_TROUSERS = "trousers";
static final String KEY_JEANS = "jeans";
static final String KEY_SHIRTS = "shirts";


ListView fancy_list_view;
    LazyAdapter fancy_list_adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fancyList = 
    new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FANCY);
    // looping through all list nodes <list>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
        map.put(KEY_TROUSERS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TROUSERS));
        map.put(KEY_JEANS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_JEANS));
        map.put(KEY_SHIRTS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SHIRTS));


        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        fancyList.add(map);
    }


    fancy_list_view=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    fancy_list_adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, fancyList);        
    fancy_list_view.setAdapter(fancy_list_adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    fancy_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) 
            {

                if(position==0)
                    {
        Intent in = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, FancyItem.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                                }



        });     
    }   
}
```

Comment: can you post some code and logcat if the app is crashing?

Comment: Squires, i have posted some code,and i am using this link for the first listview which is main listview consists main types of fabrics link:-http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/  which code i have uploaded i need to call this one when user will choose fancy list row from the main listview row

Comment: so you want to show a deatiled view on click of the item?

Comment: squires can i have your email id then i can explain you each and every thing what i exactly require, you got right but there is some more things, if no problem so send me your email address

Comment: ssmobileproductions[at]me.com (replace [at] with @)

Comment: sure, now i am sending you a hi message via email

Answer (score 0):

normally you have something like

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
                ...
                //your logic here depending on position
                }
```

so you can use the position variable to decide what listview to open next.